# rsyslog: Logs on local0 only on restart of rsyslogd

Tags: rsyslog

I have configured rsyslog.conf such that my program's log get logged in local0 facility. I have prevented logging in messages as well.

```
*.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none;local0.none                /var/log/messages

local0.*         -/var/log/myprogram.log
```

I see that on system reboot,when I run my program the logs get into `/var/log/messages` and not in `/var/log/myprogram.log`

If I were to kill `/sbin/rsyslogd` and then start again -  `rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5` - things are fine. No logs in `/var/log/messages` but in `/var/log/myprogram.log`

What could be the cause for this behaviour?

Comment: That behaviour might be a bug, what versions are you running?